# How to create a ScriptableRenderPass that renders normally, with lighting?

Tags: unity, rendering, graphics, graphics-programming, unity-urp

**What I'm trying to do:** Render GameObject(s) of a specific Layer in my custom pass. I want to do something more later, but I'm just trying to get it to render exactly as URP would for now.

I'm just learning about ScriptableRenderPass/ScriptableRendererFeature, and so I'm starting basic.

Here's what I want:

[image: Expected]

Here's what I'm getting:

[image: Actual Result]

This is what my pass's Execute looks like:

```
    public override void Execute(ScriptableRenderContext context, ref RenderingData renderingData)
    {
        CommandBuffer cmd = CommandBufferPool.Get("EnemyClearDepthPass"); // Take this outside if you don't need this to change at all.

        foreach (var renderer in _associatedObjects)
        {
            if (renderer.isVisible)
            {
                cmd.DrawRenderer(renderer, renderer.sharedMaterial);
            }
        }

        context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cmd);
        CommandBufferPool.Release(cmd);
    }
```

It looks like it's rotation (thus, its MVP matrix) is correct... but it has no lighting. And I don't know what the 2nd cube of darkness is about. So:

**Option #1)** Figure out what commands I need to pass to the command buffer in order to apply lighting... and fix whatever the dark square is about... and hope that's it when I start to draw much more complex shaders.

But then I had a thought:

**Option #2)** Maybe I could use ScriptableRenderContext.DrawRenderers(...) in order to draw it, as I presume then it would work more "out of the box".

Here's what I get, no matter what I try to do with that approach:

[image: Nothingness]

(I know I could have just said nothing... but...)

To just get started on that approach, I am just trying to make a pass that draws everything. But I can get it to work. Why?

```
using System;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;
public class JustDrawSomethingPls : ScriptableRendererFeature
{
    // https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.1/manual/containers/create-custom-renderer-feature-1.html
    class DrawEverythingPass : ScriptableRenderPass
    {
        public DrawEverythingPass() { }

        public override void Execute(ScriptableRenderContext context, ref RenderingData renderingData)
        {
            CommandBuffer cmd = CommandBufferPool.Get("DrawEverythingPass");
            // https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.DrawingSettings.html
            DrawingSettings drawingSettings = new DrawingSettings();
            drawingSettings.mainLightIndex = 0;
                SortingSettings sortingSettings = new SortingSettings();
                sortingSettings.criteria = SortingCriteria.None;
            drawingSettings.sortingSettings = sortingSettings;
            // https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.FilteringSettings.html
            FilteringSettings filteringSettings = new FilteringSettings();
            filteringSettings.excludeMotionVectorObjects = false;
            filteringSettings.layerMask = int.MaxValue;
            filteringSettings.renderingLayerMask = uint.MaxValue;
            filteringSettings.renderQueueRange = new RenderQueueRange(0, 5000); // The upper bound must be at least 0 and at most 5000
            filteringSettings.sortingLayerRange = new SortingLayerRange(0, Int16.MaxValue);
            // https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.RenderStateBlock.html
            RenderStateBlock renderStateBlock = new RenderStateBlock(RenderStateMask.Everything);

            context.DrawRenderers(renderingData.cullResults, ref drawingSettings, ref filteringSettings, ref renderStateBlock);

            // Execute the command buffer
            context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cmd);
            CommandBufferPool.Release(cmd);
        }
    }

    private DrawEverythingPass _drawEverythingPass;
    public override void Create()
    {
        _drawEverythingPass = new DrawEverythingPass();
    }
    public override void AddRenderPasses(ScriptableRenderer renderer, ref RenderingData renderingData)
    {
        renderer.EnqueuePass(_drawEverythingPass);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have any experience with the way URP does custom passes, but extrapolating from HDRP I would guess the problem with method 1 is that you are rendering all shader passes (indeed, [that seems to be the default](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.CommandBuffer.DrawRenderer.html) ), and the problem with method 2 is to do with the layer culling settings of the camera. HDRP's CustomPass has an `AggregateCullingParameters` property that you can override, but I don't know what the URP equivalent would be.

Comment: You are correct! That black square is the shadow pass (which happens at a different camera angle). I'm not sure what each of these passes are for, but that has at least got me somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I haven't full achieved what I wanted to do via the command buffer, a big step is to not use

```
cmd.DrawRenderer(renderer, renderer.sharedMaterial);
```

as it will draw all shader passes on top of each other, but instead use specific shader pass ("**myShaderPass**"):

```
cmd.DrawRenderer(renderer, renderer.sharedMaterial, 0, myShaderPass);
```

The main problem in this post was the fact that it was drawing the shadow pass on top of everything else. Note that getting lit shaders to work is going to be more work than getting an unlit shader to work via the command buffer.